# Center h2 inside a div - very basics

Tags: html, css, text, margin, text-align

I want to center h2 inside #top but vert-aliignt middle doesnt work same auto margin... I ave no idea what to do!

```
#top {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(89,144,222,.6);
}
#top h2{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Impact";
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

effect is - [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `line-height:100px; vertical-align:middle` on #top.

Comment: works. thanks. Building structure in HTML is srsly hard... Im first time trying it

Comment: This tutorial might help you on how to position and structure HTML: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` with [vertical-aling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) property .

**HTML**

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="top">  
        <h2>Personal webpage</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#table{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

#top {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(89,144,222,.6);
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#top h2{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Impact";
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzGWk/).